# Verify condition on two columns

Tags: sql, sas

I have two data sets with multiple columns and i would like to verify they have the same entries based on two columns, an example below:

Table 1

```
a | b
-----
1 | 1
1 | 3
2 | 3
2 | 4
```

Table 2

```
a | b
-----
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 3
2 | 7
```

I would like two know all the tuples in table 1 not appearing in table 2.

The output would be:

```
a | b
-----
1 | 1
2 | 4
```

It does not seem that complicated but i could not find a solution or a post about it.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: You just need a left join or a not exists.

Comment: I am working on SAS so I did not precise a database. I was not sure it would be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI standard SQL.

```
select col1, col2 
from table_1 
except
select col1, col2 
from table_2;
```

`except` returns all rows from table 1 that do not appear in table 2

Comment: Or perhaps EXCEPT ALL, depending on the desired result. (Hard to tell with the current sample data.)

Comment: [SAS Docs -SQL SET OPERATORS: SO HANDY VENN YOU NEED THEM](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/242-31.pdf)  Venn you need them... oi vey (pg 13 Except is explained)

Comment: @xQbert: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using MINUS

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2 FROM t1
MINUS
SELECT t2.col1, t2.col2 FROM t2
```

The MINUS operator is not supported in all SQL databases. It can be used in databases such as Oracle. For databases such as SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite, use the EXCEPT operator to perform this type of query.

Comment: MINUS, is that Oracle?

Comment: MINUS is Oracle's implementation of `EXCEPT`

Comment: But `MINUS` is ***not*** the "ANSI way" - it's the Oracle way.

Answer (score 0):

Two different approaches:

[SAS DOCs on using PROC SQL](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/249-30.pdf)

Using an ANTI-Join

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM table1 T1
LEFT JOIN table2 T2
  on T1.Col1 = T2.col1
 and T1.Col2 = T2.Col2
WHERE T2.Col1 is null
```

Using a correlated query and not exists

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM table2 T2
                  WHERE T1.Col1 = T2.col1
                    and T1.Col2 = T2.Col2)
```

or you could use a full outer join to find records not in Either (provided the RDBMS supports a full outer join)

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 T2
  on T1.Col1 = T2.col1
 and T1.Col2 = T2.Col2
WHERE T2.Col1 is null or T1.Col1 is null
```

or if you wanted only two columns and don't care which table has what records, your select could be

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.col1,t2.col1) as Col1, coalesce(t1.col2, t2.col2) as Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you indicated which version of SQL you were using and added some column names, but you can try something like this:

```
    Select col1, col2
    from Table 1 as A
    Left Join
    Table 2 as B
    on A.col1 = B.col1
    and A.col2 = B.col2
    where B.col1 is null
```